# Importing Social Media Followers

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I was running this code for a while on Python 2.7 in order to automatically collect the number of followers of certain accounts on Twitter and Instagram.

This code is supposed to give me the number of Twitter and Instagram followers of a basketball player in real time.

The code has stopped working this week and I cannot find a way to fix it. I would really appreciate if anyone has a solution!

```
import requests
from json import loads

Username = "nolimittb"
r = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/'+Username)
html = r.text.encode("utf-8")
text = html[html.index("window._sharedData = ")+21:]
text = (text[:text.index("};</script>")]+"}").replace('\\"', "")
dictionary= loads(text)
data = dictionary["entry_data"]["ProfilePage"][0][user]

print "Thomas Bryant Instagram:"
print str(data["followed_by"]["count"]) + ' Followers'

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
username='nolimittb31'
url = 'https://www.twitter.com/'+username
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

f = soup.find('li', class_="ProfileNav-item--followers")
title = f.find('a')['title']
print 'Thomas Bryant Twitter:'
print title

num_followers = int(title.split(' ')[0].replace(',',''))
```

Comment: What is the error it is displaying?

Comment: NameError: name 'user' is not defined

Comment: Thanks but I unortunately run into the same problem with that code @KeyurPotdar

Comment: well, `user` indeed seems to be not defined. either replace it with `Username` or define it if they're not the same variable.

Comment: Instagram may have changed their code, Twitter actually works

Comment: Thanks @OmarEinea I tried replacing it with [username], ["username"], ['username'], ["name"], ['name']. None of them work

Comment: did you try with capitalized `Username`? cuz that's the variable declared above

Comment: Yes unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

If you `print dictionary["entry_data"]["ProfilePage"][0]`, then you'll get this:

```
{
    'logging_page_id': 'profilePage_1706986508',
    'show_suggested_profiles': False,
    'graphql': {
        'user': {
            'biography': "Official IG of TB\nLos Angeles Lakers\nA Hoosier at heart!! \nI will never be the same.. In Jesus' name.. Amen",
            'blocked_by_viewer': False,
            'country_block': False,
            'external_url': 'https://www.bookcameo.com/thomasbryant',
            'external_url_linkshimmed': 'https://l.instagram.com/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bookcameo.com%2Fthomasbryant&e=ATPQyJlxPSdd8tAG-VVbepnurfbkUgrQTP8OsVKTH6d3cSec9dSlcW7JCevxuXWdZb0UtCzc',
            'edge_followed_by': {
                'count': 62109
            },
            ...
        ...
    ...
}
```

Which has a bit different structure than what you're trying to index. So, if you want to access the followers from the returned data, you'll need to access `./graphql/user/edge_followed_by/count`.

You can do that like this:

```
print dictionary["entry_data"]["ProfilePage"][0]["graphql"]["user"]["edge_followed_by"]["count"]
# Outputs: 62115
```

---

Or modifying on your code directly, it'll look like this:

```
...

data = dictionary["entry_data"]["ProfilePage"][0]["graphql"]["user"]

print "Thomas Bryant Instagram:"
print str(data["edge_followed_by"]["count"]) + ' Followers'
```

Output:

```
Thomas Bryant Instagram:
62115 Followers
```